# object-fit not performing as expected

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to use `object-fit` but it seems like the css is being ignored (just seems to be on auto mode)

The second image is what I want it to look like (or at least to have the functionality of).

HTML

```
<section
    style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/400x1000/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&')"
    class="image"
>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x1000/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&">
</section>

<br><br><br>

<section
    style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/400x1000/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&')"
    class="image contain"
>
    <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x1000/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&"
        style="visibility: hidden;"
    >
</section>
```

SCSS

```
.image {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    &.auto {
        background-size: auto;
    }
    &.contain {
        background-size: contain;
    }
    &.cover {
        background-size: cover;
    }

    img {
        // max-height: 100%;
        // max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        object-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/whb7qLku/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is in portrait mode you need to restrict the height of the image to make it work.

Either set `img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;}` or `img { height: 100%; width: 100%;}`